# Android App (5) will fail to load the external dependency (1) declared in Android Library Project (2)

Tags: android, gradle, highcharts, artifactory, jfrog-cli

[image: Failing to load external dependency in aar. when this .aar is used in Android Project]
Problem Statement: 
Android App (5) will fail to load the external dependency (1) declared in Android Library Project (2)

Please refer the diagram step by step, to arrive at the problem statement.

1. I got a highcharts-release.aar
2. I have one android library project
3. I will be adding  highcharts-release.aar(1) to (2) as external dependency

[image: added .aar into libs folder]

and added this code to, Project > build.gradle

```
 flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
```

and, module > build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name:'highcharts-release', ext:'aar') 
    .....
 }
```

to publish to artifactory,

```
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId packageName
            version = libraryVersion
            artifactId project.getName()

            // Tell maven to prepare the generated "*.aar" file for publishing
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.getByName("releaseCompileClasspath").getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'https://url/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'csapx-ui-gradle-stable-local'
            username = 'uname'
            password = 'pword'
        }
        defaults {
            // Tell the Artifactory plugin which artifacts should be published to Artifactory
            publications('aar')
            publishArtifacts = true

            // Properties to be attached to the published artifacts
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            // Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default)
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

4. I am able to see the .aar getting created in jFrog. I converted to .zip format to see the content, and I see the external dependency "highcharts-release.aar" present in the libs folder.

5.Include/Use this artifactory in the Android App project, by adding an implementation @ module gradle.

```
 implementation(group: 'com.karthik.mylibrary',
            name: 'app', version: "$rootProject.ext.highchartsVersion", ext: 'aar') {
        exclude  group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
        transitive = true
        changing = true
    }
```

and,

project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'uname'
                password 'pword'
            }
            url "https://url/artifactory/csapx-ui-gradle-stable-local"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.8.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

ext {

    // highcharts
    highchartsVersion = '1.0.0'
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'uname'
                password 'pword'
            }
            url "https://url/artifactory/csapx-ui-gradle-stable-local"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Finally, build the android application, to see the error,

[image: failed to load library]

So over all, problem statement will be, 
highcharts-release.aar > adding into another .aar > importing into app is failing.

Not able to find what is that I am missing here &/or how to fix this issue.

Please help me find the solution.

Comment: You can't upload an aar which contains another aar. Because AGP does not support fat aars (aar with embedded dependencies). You can try with a custom plugin like this [one](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android) or you need to create an additional module for your highcharts-release.aar using: "File -> New Module -> Import Jar/AAR" selecting your chart.aar and then you need to upload this module to artifctory too

Comment: I tried this way too. I am facing the same problem. I mean, the last option  "File -> New Module -> Import Jar/AAR"

Comment: After you have created the AAR module, you need to upload the module to artifactory and in your library build.gradle you need to change this: `compile(name:'highcharts-release', ext:'aar')` to this: `implementation project(':HighCharts')`

Comment: Hi @MatPag, In library project, I am doing it this way,               
          >>>
 implementation(group: 'com.karthik.highcharts',
            name: 'app', version: "$rootProject.ext.highchartsVersion", ext: 'aar') {
        exclude  group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
        transitive = true
        changing = true
    } <<<

Comment: Step 1: I created a separate/new library project, this project only has highcharts.aar in the libs folder
Step 2: Build and Push to artifactory is successfull.
Step 3: Added the implementation in the existing library project like below,

  implementation(group: 'com.karthik.highcharts',
            name: 'app', version: "$rootProject.ext.highchartsVersion", ext: 'aar') {
        exclude  group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'
        transitive = true
        changing = true
    }
Still facing the same problem, build is not successfull for the existing library project.